# Baking AO textures causes unexpected computer shutdown

Tags: texture-baking, windows

I've started experiencing unexpected shutdowns when baking AO textures. The various parts of the stalwart are all placed in one project file so that I can AO texture them all. I've done various bakes as I've gone along, but when I come to attempt the final bakes I'm starting to experience the machine simply switching off.

I've updated to blender 2.74, but the shutdowns have continued.  There's nothing in the event viewer log before the shutdown, but there are a few critical/error events when restarting after the shutdown.

I just wondered whether there's something I can do with blender settings to prevent this (I've searched several times, doesn't seem to be a common problem), or whether I need to take my problem to the Microsoft support forums (as I suspect might be the case).

Comment: To me it sounds like your computer may be over-heating.